# Is there a limit on how many oral transmitters a hadith can have?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith

Have the scholars of Hadith decided on the number of allowable oral transmitters between the Messenger of Allah and the writer of the Hadith before the Hadith is rejected simply for having too long of an oral chain?

for example, if somebody orally narrated a hadith and its chain today and had about 30 oral transmitters in between him and The Messenger of Allah, can such a hadith be rejected on the grounds of it having too long of an oral chain?

Comment: The point is the knowledge on the narrators qualification. Further all scholars look for a short narrator chain for several reasons less people means less people to check and verify and memorize and therefore a higher chancd of the report being authentic. For a muhadith of these days a narrator chain of around 28 narrators between the prophet and him would be great however a chain till 30 or 31 is still reasonsble. The shortest chains in the two Sahihs have 4 narators in between the author and the prophet, but you may also find chains with 5 or 6 narrators.

Comment: thank you, I have another Q. Is a shorter chain necessarily better than a longer chain? I ask because over a fixed time period, the narrators in the shorter chain will need to have kept the Hadith in their memories for a longer time period before transmission than the narrators in the Longer chain, over the same time period.